# Jquery - Get all other menus to slide up

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I have a drop down menu made with Jquery.

Right now, if you hover over all the menu items, their submenus will all show at the same time.

I would like that if I hover over one menu, then go to the next, that the previous menu's submenu will slide back up. As it is now, I have to hover out of the submenus for them to slide up.

To put it simpler, when hovering over a parent menu, slide up all other parent menu's submenus if they're open.

```
$("#DropDownMenu li.parent").hover(function() {
        $(this).find(".subMenu").slideDown('fast').show();

        $(this).parent().find(".subMenu").hover(function() {
        }, function() {
            $(this).parent().find(".subMenu").slideUp('slow');
        });
    });
```

The markup is basically like this,

```
<ul id="DropDownMenu">
<li class="parent"><a>Link1</a>
        <ul class="subMenu">
                <li><a>SubLink1</a></li>
                <li><a>SubLink2</a></li>
        <li><a>SubLink3</a></li>
        <li><a>SubLink4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
<li class="parent"><a>Link2</a>
        <ul class="subMenu">
                <li><a>SubLink1</a></li>
                <li><a>SubLink2</a></li>
        <li><a>SubLink3</a></li>
        <li><a>SubLink4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to figure it out! By using .siblings() I can slideUp all the other parent's submenu's.

```
$("#DropDownMenu li.parent").hover(
        function() {
            $(this).find(".subMenu").slideDown('fast');
            $(this).siblings().find(".subMenu").slideUp('slow');

            $(this).parent().find(".subMenu").hover(function() {
            }, function() {
                $(this).parent().find(".subMenu").slideUp('slow');
            });
        });
```

Comment: @Jova - that can be shortened, see my answer please.

Comment: @karim79 - I saw your answer but it does not slide up a submenu that is open if no other menu is hovered over, leaving that submenu open constantly. That is what my code does. :)

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure, maybe chain the slideUp to the slideDown?

Check out this page: http://jqueryfordesigners.com/  very good podcasts on jquery.
Youll porbbaly find an answer there